# Setting fontsize_formats button area and font button area from the DIV style

Tags: tinymce-4

I'm running TinyMCE 4 with dropdowns for font_formats and fontsize_formats.  This lets me set the font and font size of any selected text, and if I go back later and select that text, the font name and font size appear in the fontsize and font button area, as shown below:

[image: ed1]

This is all fine, but what I'd also like to do is click some other button in the toolbar, say the "Box" button in my example, and have that read the font name and font size assigned *to the DIV that the editor is attached to* and show *that* font name and size in the button areas. It's not hard for the plugin behind my Box button to read the font name and size that is applied to the DIV but I'm not seeing a way to poke the values into the font name and font size button areas. Does anyone know how to do  this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to help you. As I understood you want to Font and font size appear in the "Box" button.  Here is my sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TinyMCE4</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce_develop/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    toolbar1: 'fontselect fontsizeselect mybutton',
    fontsize_formats: "8px 10px 12px 14px 18px 20px 24px 36px",
    font_formats: "Andale Mono=andale mono,times;"+
        "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"+
        "Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;"+
        "Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;"+
        "Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;"+
        "Courier New=courier new,courier;"+
        "Georgia=georgia,palatino;"+
        "Helvetica=helvetica;"+
        "Impact=impact,chicago;"+
        "Symbol=symbol;"+
        "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"+
        "Terminal=terminal,monaco;"+
        "Times New Roman=times new roman,times;"+
        "Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;"+
        "Verdana=verdana,geneva;"+
        "Webdings=webdings;"+
        "Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats",

    setup: function(editor) {
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
        text: 'My button',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
            document.getElementsByTagName("button")[6].childNodes[0].nodeValue = editor.queryCommandValue('FontName') + " " + parseInt(editor.queryCommandValue('FontSize')) + "px";
        }
    });
    }
});
</script>
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" >
    <span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times; font-size: 14px;">Here's some</span>
    <span style="font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;">sample</span>
    <span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times; font-size: 14px;">text</span>
    </textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The main code here is :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[6].childNodes[0].nodeValue = editor.queryCommandValue('FontName') + " " + parseInt(editor.queryCommandValue('FontSize')) + "px";
```

I want to say that to get the button I used `getElementsByTagName`, I couldn't find the aproach with TinyMCE commands(sorry). So getElementsByTagName generates a array, and you should know order where your button is. In my example the button is 7th button. (After "File", "Edit", "View", "Format", "Font-family", "Font-sizes" buttons, yes they are also "button".)The array starts with zero, so our button becomes `[6]`.
Here is how my sample looks:[image: sample]

Selecting the text and press the button will give this result:[image: result]

Comment: Thank you candle!  That's not exactly what I wanted but I think the code you provided will tell me how to do what I want. My idea was to click "Box" and have that show the font size for the DIV the editor is attached to (not for the selected text) in the Font Sizes button and show the font name for the DIV in the Font Family button.  I gave you the bounty points.